# How to put limit on firebase listCollections()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

```
const data: any = await db.listCollections();
```

I need to get only limited number of collections, you can say pagination. But I didn't find any firebase query with limit on getting collections . Because the db is design like this way that you have to get all the collections, and there is too many collections.

Comment: and sometimes it also exceed read write quota for firebase.

Answer (score 0):

When using Firestore you should typically give your collections known names, so that you can repeat them in the client-side code, and generate the names for the documents.

The Firestore API isn't well suited for listing or querying collections.

I recommend pivoting, and storing the information that requires listing into documents, so that you can use the [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) APIs on documents.

Comment: now its design like this way , so how should I covert collection into document ? That the list of collection should be treated as document in order to use query or pagination.?